# How do I get my For Loop to print the maximum number in an array in Java?

Tags: java

```
 `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lengthOfArray;
    do {
            System.out.print("Enter an array length: ");
            lengthOfArray = keyboard.nextInt();
        } while (lengthOfArray <= 0);
        System.out.println();
        int[] array = new int [lengthOfArray];
        for(int c = 0; c < array.length; c++){
            array[c] = (int) (25*Math.random()) + 1;
        }
        
        for(int ix = 0; ix < array.length; ix++){
            System.out.print(array[ix] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        int max = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            max = i;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++){
                if (array[j] > array[max])
                    max = j;
            }
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[max];
            array[max] = temp;
        }
        System.out.println("The maximum of the numbers in the array is: " + array[max]);`
```

Here is my code ^^
It prints the array in order, but just keeps loading and doesn't print the maximum number. I'm really new to this so sorry if I'm dumb. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share an example input for which it doesn't work ?

Comment: you never leave the loop

Comment: For me it works, and always return a value (which not the maximum)

Comment: For me, it never leaves the loop. Is there a way to leave?

Answer (score 0):

Your double `for-loop` does sort the array in reverse order, as you swap the current index with the next `max` value

```
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    max = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[max]) {
            max = j;
        }
    }
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[max];
    array[max] = temp;
}
```

So at the end, the maximum value is at the index `0`

```
System.out.println("The maximum of the numbers in the array is: " + array[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // simple way to print an array
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is clearly an assignment, I am not sure you are allowed to use streams or not but you can use stream as follows:

```
max = Arrays.stream(array).max().getAsInt();
```